# how to display horizontal scrollview of images from the JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

my JSON response

```
 {"result":0,"data":[{"bannerslider_id":"1","img":"http:\/\/whatsinthestreet.com\/media\/bannerslider\/images\/slider1.jpg"},{"bannerslider_id":"2","img":"http:\/\/whatsinthestreet.com\/media\/bannerslider\/images\/slider2.jpg"},{"bannerslider_id":"3","img":"http:\/\/whatsinthestreet.com\/media\/bannerslider\/images\/slider3.jpg"},{"bannerslider_id":"4","img":"http:\/\/whatsinthestreet.com\/media\/bannerslider\/images\/slider4.jpg"}]}
```

I wrote code like this

```cxx
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whatsinthestreet.com/allbanners.php"] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data ,NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,NSError * _Nullable error){
        NSLog(@"response %@",response);
        NSLog(@"data %@",data);
        NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
        NSLog(@"dict%@",dict);
       NSArray *array;
        array=[dict valueForKey:@"data"];
       NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

I got the response as

```
 dict{
    data =     (
                {
            "bannerslider_id" = 1;
            img = "http://whatsinthestreet.com/media/bannerslider/images/slider1.jpg";
        },
                {
            "bannerslider_id" = 2;
            img = "http://whatsinthestreet.com/media/bannerslider/images/slider2.jpg";
        },
                {
            "bannerslider_id" = 3;
            img = "http://whatsinthestreet.com/media/bannerslider/images/slider3.jpg";
        },
                {
            "bannerslider_id" = 4;
            img = "http://whatsinthestreet.com/media/bannerslider/images/slider4.jpg";
        }
    );
    result = 0;
}
```

How can I access the image from these values to get horizontal scrollview of images?

Comment: [array valueforkey:@"img"] objectAtIndex:0] you got first banner image

Comment: Where is your scroll view code? where are you creating image?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whatsinthestreet.com/allbanners.php"] completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data ,NSURLResponse * _Nullable response,NSError * _Nullable error){
        NSLog(@"response %@",response);
        NSLog(@"data %@",data);
        NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
        NSLog(@"dict%@",dict);
       NSArray *array;
        array=[dict objectForKey:@"data"];
       NSLog(@"%@",array);
       for(id obj in array)
       {
            NSString *urlStr=[obj objectForKey:@"img"];
        }
}
```

Comment: @Bhavani chada now you have to convert urlsrt to NSURL object and you can move on.... CHEERS